# Adding data via Admin not visible in html template until restart server (python manage.py runserver)

Tags: python, django

Example

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models  
class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Book  
admin.site.register(Book)
```

**class Home(TemplateView):**

```
books = Book.objects.all()  

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):  
    context ['books'] = self.books  
    return context
```

**index.html**

```
  {% for b in books %}
       <h2> {{ b.name}} </h2>
  {% endfor %}
```

If I add a new Book via Django administration I need to restart the server 
in order for the new value to be visible

How can I auto-refresh the view if any data is changed via djano admin
without having to restart server (python manage.py runserver)

All help would be appreciated as I'm stuck

can i use  refresh_from_db in the view  ?

Comment: There's nothing in the code you have shown here that would cause this. Normally that happens when you define something at module or class level. Are you sure this is all the relevant code? (In particular, the view seems incomplete, since you neither define nor return `context` from the `get_context_data`.)

Comment: sorry that was a snippet and not complete code but context is returned

Answer (score 1):

Since you have defined the `books` queryset as an attribute of the `Home` class, the query will only be evaluated once - the first time it is iterated over. You need to recreate the queryset on every request

```
class Home(TemplateView):

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):  
        context['books'] = Book.objects.all() 
        return context
```

Comment: how do I recreate the queryset on every request ?

Comment: My answer contains the code to recreate the queryset, `get_context_data` is called on every request

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using a TemplateView here. What you are doing is covered by the List view class. If you use that, and define `model`, you don't need to override `get_context_data` at all. So it's just:

```
class Home(ListView):
    model = Book
```

And that's it. Django will know to query all Books on every request.

Comment: II'm still quite confused but

Comment: What are you confused about?